# How to provide autocomplete suggestions that don't match on prefix in zsh completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a zsh auto completion function for a command called `gd` which does a fuzzy search based on the `$words[CURRENT]` value and return suggestions. The search is working fine but zsh does not show any candidates because the entered text is not a prefix of the suggestion.

e.g.

```
% gd hw
```

Might generate the completion `oh hello there, world`

But zsh won't show that because `hw` is not found at the start of the suggestion.

Can I make zsh offer the suggestion as something that would replace the current word when chosen?

Here's a simplified version of my completion script in a file called `_gd` which is in my `fpath`:

```bsh
#compdef gd

_gd() {
  local -a list

  clue="$words[CURRENT]"

      pattern=""
      for i in $(seq $#clue)
      do
        pattern="$pattern.*${clue[i]}"
      done
      while read dir
      do
        list=( $list $dir )
      done <<<$(grep "$pattern" ~/.recent-dirs)

  _describe gd list
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of that `_gd` function and just add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|?=**'
```

This tells the completion code to allow any number of additional between and around what you’ve types. With this, Zsh can now fuzzy complete *anything*.

- `r:X|Y=Z` looks for all non-overlapping substrings that match pattern `XY` and makes it so the part matched by `X` *also* matches anything matched by pattern `Z` when checking for matching completions.
- `?` matches any one character.
- If `X` or `Y` equals `*`, it matches any number of consecutive characters.
- If `Z` equals `*`, it matches any number of consecutive characters *except* anything matched by `Y`.
- If `Z` equals `**`, it matches any number of consecutive characters.
- In `r:|?=**`, `X` equals the empty string.
- By default, Zsh already adds a wildcard to the end of your input, thus completing the circle for full fuzzy matching.

You can find the documentation over here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's made it simpler. Wonder what that `'r:|?=**'` does?!

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit more info. Here’s the documentation, if you’re interested: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control

Comment: Hi Marlon, follow up question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590472/zsh-fuzzy-pattern-matching-removes-typed-characters if you're interested!

Comment: @MarlonRichert This is cool, but I couldn't make it work for my related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331610/why-does-zsh-bashcompinit-not-accept-completions-that-dont-share-a-prefix-with If I'm reading your answer right, setting the zstyle as you do should allow a function to complete `fo<TAB>` to `blah` should work, but no dice in my experiments.  Do you know why this trick isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

This is hack while I wait on more wise answers...

What I've done is made my suggestion generator produce suggestions like:

```
hw»oh hello there, world
```

Because the command (actually a function) is in my control, I simply strip off the rubbish at the start:

```
input="${input#*»}"
```

But it would be nice to know how to do it properly.