# zsh fuzzy pattern matching removes typed characters

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm using the following in my zshrc:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]} r:|?=**'
```

(which is thanks to [Marlon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587943/23542))

But I'm finding some odd behaviour. e.g. take the following test case:

```
% tree zsh-test 
zsh-test
├── a-xx
├── b-xx
└── somefile
```

Then typing `ls zsh-test/xx` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> I might have expected to see `a-xx` and `b-xx` listed as possiblities. Instead, nothing is listed *and* the `xx` part of what I typed is *removed*!

I think what's happening is `xx` is generating two options, then zsh is looking for a common prefix, not finding one and so replacing my text with nothing. Which is not very helpful. I've [RTM](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) but that's not helped me with the goal of finding an intuitive fuzzy matcher pattern.

Is there a way I can get it to show the candidates that match the pattern, without removing my pattern?

The weird thing about this behaviour is that I can't even get used to it because if I'm inside the `zsh-test` dir and I type `ls xx` <kbd>Tab</kbd> then it works as expected - showing the two candidates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Zsh sees `zsh-test/` as an unambiguous prefix in the first case, whereas in the second case, there is no unambiguous prefix. (Yes, there's an unambiguous suffix, but Zsh doesn't do anything with that, unfortunately.) And by default, if Zsh sees an unambiguous prefix, then the first press of <kbd>Tab</kbd> will simply insert that prefix, possibly deleting characters you've already typed.

You can test this by entering the following into the shell:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]} r:|?=**'
bindkey '^I' complete-word
zle -C complete-word complete-word complete-word

complete-word() {
  _main_complete;
  compadd -x "unambiguous prefix: '${compstate[unambiguous]}'";
  compstate[list]='list force';
}
```

Then, try your two cases again. For the first case, you will see `unambiguous prefix: 'zsh-test/'`. For the second case, you will see `unambiguous prefix: ''`

There is, unfortunately, no way to *configure* Zsh to get the behavior you want. However, if you are willing to go a bit deeper down the rabbit hole, then the behavior you desire can be achieved by adding the following script to your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
zmodload -i zsh/complist
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]} r:|?=**'
bindkey '^I' complete-word
zle -C complete-word menu-select complete-word

complete-word() {
  _main_complete;
  compstate[list]='list';
  local word=$PREFIX$SUFFIX
  (( compstate[unambiguous_cursor] <= ${#word} )) && compstate[insert]='menu';
}
```

- `compstate[list]='list'` makes sure that completions are automatically listed when there's more than one match available.
- The last line checks whether the default behavior would delete any part of the current word that the cursor is on and, if so, instead inserts the first item from the list.
- The `menu-select` (provided by `zsh/complist`) in `zle -C complete-word menu-select complete-word` then lets you use your choice of <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the <kbd>arrow keys</kbd> to select a different item from the list.

Tuning Zsh's completion system this way can get fairly complex rather quickly and there are many parts of it that are not all that well-documented. I highly encourage you to check out my [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete), which customizes the Zsh completion system to do out-of-the-box what most people would expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd try your plugin. I installed with antigen (first plugin manager I duckduckgo'ed) sourcing from the default ohmyzsh repo and it doesn't do anything; I installed from marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete and I get floods of  ` _autocomplete.async-list-choices:30: command not found: zpty` every key press! (pls say if this is not the right place to have this conversation)

Comment: Ah, adding `antigen bundle mafredri/zsh-async` before `antigen bundle marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete` fixes that. (but the ohmyzsh bundled one did nothing with or without that).

Comment: Re "I installed with antigen (first plugin manager I duckduckgo'ed)": If you're not committed to any plugin manager yet, I would highly recommend using Zinit: https://github.com/zdharma/zinit

Comment: Re "sourcing from the default ohmyzsh repo": `zsh-autocomplete` is not included with oh-my-zsh. So, I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Re "adding antigen bundle mafredri/zsh-async before antigen bundle marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete fixes that": Strange. I've also encountered another bug in Antigen that can prevent `zsh-autocomplete` from working: https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/703 As I said before, I would recommend not using Antigen, but try Zinit instead.

Comment: Or just install manually. That works fine, too.

Comment: @artfulrobot I changed the `<` in my answer to `<=`, because I noticed there's an edge where the widget would do nothing. Now it should work for all cases. 

Answer (score 0):

With menu completion you do get two, `zsh-test/a-xx` and `zsh-test/b-xx`. Quite why the xx is removed I can't tell you. But from what you're saying it seems you trying to get fuzzy matching and there may be easier ways.

`'r:|?=**'` is quite aggressive. In terms of fuzzyness, it allows extra characters between every single typed character but doesn't handle things like transposed characters. Just `'b:=*'` will allow substrings and the `_approximate` completer handles approximations in a somewhat more controlled manner, preferring matches that require fewer corrections.

Comment: The `_approximate` completer is _really slow_. I prefer not to use it. Also, it tends to generate too many false positives.

Comment: `b:=*` does not give you fuzzy matching. It does not let you type `bky` and get `bindkey`. `r:|?=**` does.

Comment: As I stated, `b:=*` does substrings - I was suggesting it be combined with `_approximate`.. You can configure `_approximate`, a common setup is one error for every 3 characters typed. `zstyle -e ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 'reply=( $(( ($#PREFIX+$#SUFFIX)/3 )) numeric )'`